# Using Microsoft attributes with Google TTS

Tags: text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech, ssml

In my application, I am already using [Google TTS](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml) but I am amazed by [Microsoft TTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup?tabs=csharp) because they are providing a lot more useful attributes than Google. Since I am more familiar with Google, I would like to keep my implementation but would still like to be able to use MS attributes like:

```xml
<mstts:express-as style="cheerful">
    That'd be just amazing!
</mstts:express-as>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are no style attributes in Google Text-to-Speech, but you can change the Standard voice to a WaveNet voice[1].

The WaveNet voice synthesizes speech with more human-like emphasis and inflection on syllables, phonemes, and words. You can see all the supported voices in Google Text-to-Speech[2].

[1]https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/wavenet#wavenet_voices

[2]https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices